# Python numpy vectorization for heat dispersion

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, heat

I'm supposed to write a code to represent heat dispersion using the finite difference formula given below.

`()=((−1)[+1,] + (−1) [−1,] +(−1)[,+1] + (−1)[,−1])/4`
The formula is supposed to produce the  result only for a time step of 1. So, if an array like this was given:

```
100   100   100   100   100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100   100   100   100   100
```

The resulting array at time step 1 would be:

```
100   100   100   100   100  
100    50    25    50   100   
100    25     0    25   100  
100    50    25    50   100  
100   100   100   100   100
```

I know the representation using for loops would be as follows, where the array would have a minimum of 2 rows and 2 columns as a precondition:

```
h = np.copy(u)
for i in range(1,h.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range (1, h.shape[1]-1):
        num = u[i+1][j] + u[i-1][j] + u[i][j+1] + u[i][j-1]
        h[i][j] = num/4
```

But I cannot figure out how to vectorize the code to represent heat dispersion. I am supposed to use numpy arrays and vectorization and am not allowed to use for loops of any kind, and I think I am supposed to rely on slicing, but I cannot figure out how to write it out and have started out with.

```
r, c = h.shape
if(c==2 or r==2):
    return h
```

I'm sure that if the rows=2 or columns =2 then the array is returned as is, but correct me if Im  wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
h[1:-1,1:-1] = (h[2:,1:-1] + h[:-2,1:-1] + h[1:-1,2:] + h[1:-1,:-2]) / 4
```

This solution uses slicing where:

- `1:-1` stays for indices 1,2, ..., LAST - 1
- `2:` stays for 2, 3, ..., LAST
- `:-2` stays for 0, 1, ..., LAST - 2

During each iteration only the inner elements (indices 1..LAST-1) are updated